# AutoRun.inf code not behaving

Tags: autorun

Hey everyone just been working on an autorun.inf to run a bat which will copy pictures from my iphone uploaded folder to my external HDD. but the autorun refuses to work, I have made the bat file which works perfectly but when the portable HDD is plugged in it wont auto run, the label comes up but nothing else not even the option to run it.

```
[autorun]    
label=School-Work        
icon=test.ico    
Action="F:\Launch.bat"    
action=start Iphone photos backup
```

so far everything says thats correct, I have also tried action=Launch.bat it just wont load.
any ideas or suggestions, I have read that it is a security feature of windows 7. if so anyway to change my system to allow me to?

Comment: Just a side note: be careful with assigning a fix drive letter. Sometimes your current drive will get a new one.

Comment: yeah thanks, was thinking that but thought worth a short to see if it atleast works sadly hasnt though.